# SDL throws "invalid window" error, can't draw anything to my window

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl

My SDL program's (C++, compiled with Mingw) window can't draw anything. When `SDL_GetError()` is called, I get the error "invalid window", except for the `GetError` in the `pushFramebufferToScreen` function, in which case I get `"SDL_UpperBlit: passed a Null surface"`. The program compiles just fine and the library also seems to be linked well. The purpose of this program is to test how to draw a framebuffer to a window for an emulator.

- Troubleshooting parts that might have caused problems
- Make sure SDL gets initialized properly
- See other SDL projects to see if I'm doing anything wrong
- Make sure I've linked SDL properly and all my SDL dlls are in my executable folder

setup.h:

```cpp
bool init_SDLComponents(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Joystick* joystick, SDL_Surface* surface)
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)<0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<SDL_GetError();
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout<<"SDL initiated properly\n\n";
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Name",
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               320, 288,
                               0);

    if (!window)
    {  
        std::cout << "Can't make window\n";
        return false;
    }


    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if (!renderer)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't make renderer" << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }

    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    if (!surface)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't make surface" << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

ppu.h:

```cpp
SDL_Surface** windowSurface; //pointer to the surface of my window
const int HEIGHT = 160;
const int WIDTH = 144;
const int CHANNELS = 3;
uint8_t framebuffer [HEIGHT * WIDTH * CHANNELS];
```

ppu.cpp:

```cpp
PPU::pushFramebufferToScreen()
{
    memset (framebuffer, 0x00, sizeof(framebuffer);
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom ((void*) framebuffer,
                                                             WIDTH,
                                                             HEIGHT,
                                                             CHANNELS * 8, //bits per channel
                                                             WIDTH * CHANNELS, /pitch
                                                             0x0000FF,
                                                             0x00FF00,
                                                             0xFF0000
                                                    );

    SDL_BlitSurface (surface, NULL, *windowSurface, NULL);
    std::cout<<SDL_GetError();
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

}
```

finally, main.cpp:

```cpp
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
SDL_Joystick* joystick = NULL;
SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

init_SDLComponents(window, renderer, joystick, surface);
//std::cout<<SDL_GetError();

PPU ppu;
ppu.windowSurface = &surface;   
ppu.pushBufferToScreen();
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
SDL_Delay(2000);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
```

I excepted that my window's colour would be set to blank instead of the default white. However, all I get is `invalidWindow` errors, and the `UpperBlit` error in the framebuffer function.

Comment: Why isn't `init_SDLComponents()` taking its arguments by reference or double-pointer?  Right now you're not actually propagating the new values back outside the function.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` if you've got a renderer going?  That's specifically forbidden by [the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface#Remarks).

Comment: @genpfault I could not be more grateful to you, your answer saved me. Hadn't noticed that.